# What does "a dead end" mean? Does it mean "dead"?

Tags: word-usage

[image]

> Taiwan independence is ‘a dead end’
>   Xi Jinping calls on Taiwan to reject independence and embrace ‘peaceful reunification’ with China.

What does it mean...?
I'm wondering, was he dying?
Or is his career ended?

Comment: Related: [Is there an idiomatic way to say “go to the path of no way out”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168676/is-there-an-idiomatic-way-to-say-go-to-the-path-of-no-way-out/168723#168723)

Comment: ‘a dead end’ in Chinese can be 死路.

Comment: Also see at EL&U, *[What is the origin of “dead end” on a road sign?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79562)*

Comment: https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/dead_end

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A dead end** is the name given to a street that has no exit. That's to say, the only way out is the way you came in. The street leads nowhere.

The expression is used to describe ventures, plans, jobs, ideas and anything else which (somebody thinks) are futile or ill-judged and will lead nowhere.

Xi Jingping is saying that the idea of independence for Taiwan is a non-starter. It has no chance of being realised. Taiwan's future, in his view, lies in reunification with China. Any talk of independence for Taiwan is fruitless. Such independence will never come about.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dead-end

Comment: Sorry i could understand TT street? Is it like a maze? Maybe should I'm studying grammars?

Comment: It's not a maze. It's a (short) side-street. There's only one entrance and exit. Also known as a cul-de-sac or blind-alley